# Получить ключ элемента из многомерного массива

Tags: php, массивы, выборка

Есть многомерный массив такого вида:

```
Array (   
[0] => Array ( [0] => 140 [1] => #708090 [2] => S [3] => 30 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 )  
 [1] => Array ( [0] => 140 [1] => #DCDCDC [2] => 2XL [3] => 29 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 )  
 [2] => Array ( [0] => 140 [1] => #DCDCDC [2] => L [3] => 24 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 )  
 [3] => Array ( [0] => 140 [1] => #DCDCDC [2] => S [3] => 23 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 ))
```

Известны цвет и размер т.е `[1] => #... [2] => ...` каждого элемента в массиве. Как можно получить ключ или весь массив зная эти данные через php. Ключ нужно получить этот
 `**[0]** => Array(...)`
 `**[1]** => Array(...)` и т.д

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел еще одну функцию которая перебирает в цикле элементы которые надо найти. Незнаю какая из функций работает быстрее:

```
function getColor($arr, $color, $size){
   foreach($arr as $key => $val){
       if($val[1] == $color && $val[2] == $size){
           return $key;
       }
   }
}
$key = getColor($array , $color, $size);  
echo $key;
```

Answer (score 1):

Получилась достаточно тяжелая и ненадежная функция, но что поделать, вообще такие штуки надо сразу в запросе к бд предусматривать

```
    $array = [
        [140, "#708090", "S"],
    [140, "#DCDCDC", "2XL"],
    [140, "#DCDCDC", "S"],
[140, "#708090", "L"],
];

/**
 * Находит главный ключ многомерного массива по значения столбцов color и size
 */
function findMainKey($array, $color, $size ) {
    $outputKey = NULL;
    $colorArray = array_column($array, 1);
    $sizeArray = array_column($array, 2);
    while ( count($colorArray) > 0 && $outputKey === NULL ) {
       $key = array_search($color, $colorArray);

       if ( isset($sizeArray[$key]) && $sizeArray[$key] == $size )
          $outputKey = $key;

       unset($colorArray[$key], $sizeArray[$key]);
    }
    return $outputKey;
}

// создаем 2 массива, из колонок, по которым будем проводить поиск.


$key = findMainKey($array , "#DCDCDC", "S");
echo $key; // 2
```

Comment: Обновил ответ, предыдущий скрипт был не совсем рабочим :)

Comment: По секрету скажу у меня все 3 метода заработали. Спасибо очень помогли!

Comment: в ходе тестирования выявилось что функция не работает когда надо найти первый элемент массива т.е когда `$key` должен быть равен `0` выдает ошибку

Comment: @AziretKadykeev какая ошибка?

Comment: @AziretKadykeev поменял чуть-чуть условие while, оказалось что 0 == NULL

Comment: вы лучший спасибо

Comment: Я еще заметил что когда порядок ключей в массиве хаотичный т.е   `Array([2] => Array() [5] => Array())` и мне нужно вытащить ключ №5 функция думает что это 1, но ничего решил проблему переиндексировав массив с `array_values()`